# Did Kindle contrast get better or is my old Kindle growing old?

Tags: kindle, e-ink, display

I have a 4th generation (iirc) basic Kindle which I bought new. My mom has a newer, also basic, Kindle that is now one year old, also bought new. The screen of her Kindle looks lighter / whiter than mine, and the writing feels darker/blacker. Is it because the e-ink technology improved, or did my Kindle lose contrast with use/age? I don't remember thinking my screen was too grey when my Kindle was new, and now I do because I've seen a better one xD The contrast on my Kindle is definitely (still) good enough to read, or I wouldn't be asking.

TL;DR : can e-ink lose contrast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently E-ink does age due to various physical processes. There is
lost of contrast (greying), but also freezing of some microcapsules to
the black state where they are kept too consistently in that state (typical
for some parts of device state display which stays on-screen).

I am not a specialist, but you can get more (layman level) details
on the web, such as the article [Aging of e-ink screens](http://e-ink-reader.ru/eink_degradation_en.php), which come
with other articles on display technology.

Comment: I looked closer and I've noticed that the greying isn't even, like the article says. So this might be it. Thank you ^^